# My iOS UIScrollView refreshes only off-screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my iOS app, I do have my UIScrollView that contains UITableView with classes (cells) containing UIImages.
Now I do need to update the UIImages programmatically.
However the visible part of my UIScrollView does not update, unless I do scroll the changed item (UIImage) off the visible screen and back.
I've tried setNeedsLayout, setNeedsDidsplay for my UIScrollView, UITableView -- no success.
Any idea on what I could do wrong, or how can I force the ScrollView to update without actual scrolling?

Comment: can you provide some more information since it is not clear at what point you want to update the tableView and scrollView is not required if you are using tableView since tableView inherits from scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
At first, UITableView inside UIScrollView was unnecessary since UITableView scrolls itself.
The solution was to use ReloadData method for my TableView.

Answer (score 0):

this is because tableView calls `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` when cell reappear on screen so that it can reuse cell object to save memory, so call `tableView.reloadData()` or `func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)` whenever ( after data is changed obviously ) you want to reload the entire tableView or particular cell respectively.
And no need to use scrollView for tableView since tableView inherits from scrollView.